# Resolve page.evaluate() in puppeteer after user triggered event

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I am running `page.evaluate()` that has to return what I manually typed in an input field on the page. I wrote a code that I know won't work but it shows the intent behind it:

```
let inputText = await page.evaluate(() => {
    // some non-automated process done by hand
    let sendButton = document.querySelector(".button");
    sendButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
        let text = document.querySelector(".input").value;
        return text;
    }, false);
    // wait for text?

});
console.log(inputText);
```

How do I make puppeteer wait for my event trigger inside the `page.evaluate()` before returning my typed text back to nodejs context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't make `evaluate` wait for that, but you can use [exposeFunction](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.14.0/docs/api.md#pageexposefunctionname-puppeteerfunction) to register a callback function.

```js
await page.exposeFunction('processInput', inputText => console.log(inputText));

await page.evaluate(() => {
    // some non-automated process done by hand
    let sendButton = document.querySelector(".button");
    sendButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
        let text = document.querySelector(".input").value;

        processInput(text);

    }, false);
});
```

As [miyagisan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7907844/miyagisan) commented, and it's a great idea, it is also possible to return a promise:

```js
const inputText = await page.evaluate(() => { 
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
        let sendButton = document.querySelector(".button"); 
        sendButton.addEventListener("click", () => { 
            let text = document.querySelector(".input").value; 
            resolve(text); 
        }, false); 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I did not know you can do this. It resembles a callback pattern since the rest of the main puppeteer scope continues to the end.

Comment: If you want to modify your answer, you can change that it is technically possible to stop `page.evaluate()` and wait for a promise inside to resolve. Sorry for formatting.

```const inputText = await page.evaluate(() => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let sendButton = document.querySelector(".button");
        sendButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
            let text = document.querySelector(".input").value;
            resolve(text);
        }, false);
    });
});```

Comment: Great idea @miyagisan I love it. Added to the answer.